# Modifying Rules in Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using Sonar to list the violations in code. While, a lot of the violations are legitimate, some of the violations that it shows are a bit too far-fetched.

For example, I want Sonar to exclude violations in logger statements and also in annotated JAXB classes. Since, these classes are widely spread across multiple packages in the project, I am not able to exclude any specific package.

Is there a suitable way to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: give the jaxb classes an own (exclusive) subpackage like bla.*.jaxb, where only jaxb generated classes are (repeat pattern for each project). Then you can exclude using **/jaxb/*.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Switch Off Violations Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin) to control precisely which violations should not be reported. Check the documentation for more information.

And as @oers said, it would be best to group your JAXB classes in specific packages to exclude them all with the "sonar.excludes" property.